# Pure java ZeroMQ clients?

Tags: java, message-queue, zeromq

I am trying to use ZeroMQ's pub sub messaging, but the client side requires the code to be all Java. I understand that ZeroMQ has a Java binding but that still relies on a c library, therefore I am unable to use it. Is there a ZeroMQ client I can use to connect to the server, or is the implementation simple enough for me to do myself?

Comment: Did you ever use RabbitMQ? It has pure Java client.

I never tried ZeroMQ but i think you will have a pretty class to correspond with ZeroMQ:

http://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/org/zeromq/ZMQ.java

Comment: Are you mandated for any reason in using ZeroMQ ? I had never heard of it, not that that implies it is bad. There are soooo many other options around that are better known and will provide what you ask for.

Comment: Well I need a fast, lightweight messaging, and thought that ZeroMQ was a good fit. However, I might try something else if necessary.

Comment: I have the same question.  ZeroMQ looks like exactly what I want on the server side, but I'm wanting to use Android for the client.  Those desires leave me asking the same question as fanar.

Comment: Any reason not to choose one of the answers? (I didn't write a definite "no", as someone may have written a Java-only library by looking at the wire protocol but if this is the case it hasn't been publicized)

Comment: I would be interested in this as well, and a Crossroads-IO client would be similarly acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, I think it is safe to assume that the answer to your question is **no**.

A pure Java client would need to use the same wire protocol as the native C++ implementation; documenting this protocol has not been done yet and was on the 0MQ developers TODO list last time I checked.

Answer (score 14):

I'm working on pure java ZeroMQ.

https://github.com/miniway/jeromq

Even it is very early stage and might not quite fit for production usage right now.

But I hope it would help, as I made it with a passion.

Comment: This library is now also hosted at ZeroMQ's github profile. https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq . And the ZeroMQ wiki suggest this library over using the NDK solution.

Comment: Min: Just wanted to say thanks for porting it to pure java. I have been using jeromq version 0.2.0 (will be upgrading to 0.3.1 soon) in prod for about 5 months now. Pub/Sub, Dealer/Router and a custom majordomo pattern, works like a charm!

Comment: If I had an old zeroMQ PUSH, would a jeromq PULL client be able to pick that up (given socket number etc.) ?

Answer (score 6):

The zeromq web site claims support for android on the follow page:

http://www.zeromq.org/distro:android

which includes a tarball of zeromq pre-built for android, using the NDK (Native Development Kit) which bridges Java apps to standard c libraries.

Comment: A quick correction to this: it requires an *unofficial* NDK, not the one that comes from Google.

Answer (score 3):

Note : I am assuming that you have installed ZeroMQ and google protoc successfully

I have one example where I am sending some messages from ZeroMQ Publisher to Subscriber using google protocol buffer..

**test.proto file is**

```
option java_package = "com.example.tutorial"; 
option java_outer_classname = "TestProtos";

message Test {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

now first compile it with protoc compiler as

```
$protoc -I=. --java_out=. test.proto
```

So this will generate `TestProtos.java` file in your current directories 
`/com/example/tutorial` folder

---------------------------------end of protocol buffer steps--------------------------

**Publisher code is** 
  file name : Publisher.java

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import com.example.tutorial.TestProtos.Test;

public class Publisher {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
        ZMQ.Socket publisher = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);

        // Subscriber tells us when it's ready here
        ZMQ.Socket sync = context.socket(ZMQ.PULL);

        sync.bind("tcp://*:5561");

        // We send updates via this socket
        publisher.bind("tcp://*:5562");

        System.out.println("Publisher Running");

        // Wait for synchronization request
        sync.recv(0);

        Test testzmq =
              Test.newBuilder()
                .setId(1234)
                .setName("Pritam Kharat")
                .setEmail("pritam@gmail.com")
                .build();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        int request_nbr;
        for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
            //System.out.println(request_nbr);
            publisher.send(testzmq.toByteArray(), 0); //serialization
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        long diff = (end - start);
        System.out.println("time taken to send messages "+ request_nbr +" is :" +diff);
    }
}
```

**Subscriber Code is**
file name : Subscriber.java

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import com.example.tutorial.TestProtos.Test;


public class Subscriber {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

        // Connect our subscriber socket
        ZMQ.Socket subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
        subscriber.setIdentity("hello".getBytes());

        // Synchronize with the publisher
        ZMQ.Socket sync = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);

        subscriber.subscribe("".getBytes());
        subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5562");
        sync.connect("tcp://localhost:5561");

        sync.send("".getBytes(), 0);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        int request_nbr;
        for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
            byte[] rawBytes = subscriber.recv(0);
            try{
                Test data = Test.parseFrom(rawBytes); //deserialization
             //   System.out.println(data);
            }
            catch ( Exception e ) {
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        long diff = (end - start);
        System.out.println("time taken to receive messages "+ request_nbr +" is :" +diff);
    }
}
```

That is all..you are done with your code..
Now just run these Publisher and subscriber codes..

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no pure Java implementation of `0mq`. As you say, there is a Java language binding but it requires a native library to function. A pure Java replacement for the library would not be trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short spec on the wire protocol used by ZeroMQ at http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:13.  With that you should at least be able to write the protocol portions of the code.  You would still need to write the parts that deal with ZeroMQ sockets and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

The [javazmq](https://github.com/jhawk28/javazmq) project started in Aug of 2011 claims to implement a subset of ZeroMQ in pure Java. Not sure of the completeness of it at this point.